# Detect white block in image using EmguCV

Tags: image-processing, emgucv

I am using EmguCV in C#.NET, and am trying to isolate or detect a white rectangle in an image (photo). We have no control over the quality of the photo's we receive. The plan is to find this rectangle and perform a number of processing steps to increase the chances of the ocr working (we are trying to detect the line of text above the big black box).

Sample image available here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJjW4.jpg

I have tried many of the tutorials and sample projects - edge detection, sample splitting, LicensePlateRecognition, ShapeDetection, SURFFeature, TrafficSignRecognition. But with no success.

The requirement for this is not real-time, but it can't take 3 hours to process one image either.

I am hoping to pre-process the image, such that a Canny Edge detect and HoughLines and FindContours will return me shapes, and I can find this rectangle based on a minimum size and width-height ratio.

Any help on a strategy to detect the white box will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it could be: First smooth the image.

```
Image<Bgr, byte> theSmoothImage = theImage.SmoothBlur(25, 25);
```

Or even better:

```
 Image<Bgr, byte> theSmoothImage = theImage.SmoothMedian(35);
```

The Split the image in the channels

```
Image<Gray, byte>[] theChannels = theSmoothImage.Split();
```

Then try to blob out the white rectangle in channel 3 =>
theChannels[2]